# How to determine if a property is one of my defined classes using System.Reflection

Tags: c#, system.reflection

According to this example:

```
public class a
{
    public string a1 {get; set;} = "va1";
    public int a2 {get; set;} = 20;
}

public class b
{
   public string b1 {get; set;} = "vb1";
   public int b2 {get; set;} = 40;
}

public class c
{
    public string c1 {get; set;} = "vc1";
    public int c2 {get; set;} = 60;
    public a class_a {get; set;} = new a();
    public b class_b {get; set;} = new b();
}
```

I'm trying to build a method that recursively returns all properties values, in this case for `class c`, but I'd like to make it generic for any other class.

```
static void GetValues(Object obj)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.Name == "a" || property.PropertyType.Name == "b")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"--- Properties class: {property.PropertyType.Name} ---");
            GetValues(property.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Type: {property.PropertyType.Name}  {property.Name} = {property.GetValue(obj, null).ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

That function returns this result:

```
Type: String  c1 = vc1
Type: Int32  c2 = 60
--- Properties class: a ---
Type: String  a1 = va1
Type: Int32  a2 = 20
--- Properties class: b ---
Type: String  b1 = vb1
Type: Int32  b2 = 40
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to know if a property is of type `class` instead of check specifically for class `a` or `b`?

I'd like to replace this line of code:

```
if (property.PropertyType.Name == "a" || property.PropertyType.Name == "b")
```

by something like:

```
if (property.IsClass)
```

I've set up this example on **[Rextester](https://rextester.com/SWVWD68457)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Reflection you can query the properties for any type. Note that structs may also have properties. So it would make sense to recurse all the types, not just classes.

But note that this might not make sense for some built-in types like `string` having a `Length` property and `DateTime` having many properties like `DayOfWeek` and `Ticks`. And worse, it has a property `Date` being a `DateTime` again, creating an infinite recursion. So by trial an error you might have to exclude some types or even implement a mechanism detecting recursions or at least limit the maximum level of nesting.

Here an example with exclusions:

```
private static readonly HashSet<Type> ExcludedTypes = 
    new HashSet<Type> { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime) };

static void GetValues(Object obj, int level)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties) {
        if (property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0) { // Exclude indexers
            Console.Write(new string(' ', 4 * level));
            Type pt = property.PropertyType;
            object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
            Console.WriteLine($"{pt.Name} {property.Name} = {value}");
            if (value != null && !ExcludedTypes.Contains(pt)) {
                GetValues(value, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result of calling `GetValues(new c(), 0);`
(I added `DateTime a3` and `Point b3` properties to make it more interesting):

```
String c1 = vc1
Int32 c2 = 60
a class_a = StackOverflowTests3.RecurseProperties+a
    String a1 = va1
    Int32 a2 = 20
    DateTime a3 = 23.10.2020 16:55:01
b class_b = StackOverflowTests3.RecurseProperties+b
    String b1 = vb1
    Int32 b2 = 40
    Point b3 = {X=7,Y=3}
        Boolean IsEmpty = False
        Int32 X = 7
        Int32 Y = 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. It can be hard to set up a list of all possible excluded types.

Answer (score 3):

You're so nearly there - you just need to remember whether you're asking whether the *property type* is a class:

```cs
if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
```

Comment: @McNets: Yes, because `string` is a class.

Comment: @McNets: It's unclear what you mean by "a structure defined as a class" - `string` *is* such a class. In terms of "built-in" - how *exactly* do you define that? Would you count (say) types in Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) as "built-in"? They're not classes *you* wrote. What about things like ASP.NET Core? It's not part of the framework directly, but it *is* distributed with the .NET Core SDK... Basically, you need to be *really* precise about your criteria. Once you've expressed it clearly, it will probably be easy to turn into code... but without that clarity to start with, you've got no chance.

Comment: @McNets: I'd also say that I've answered the question you asked - if you actually meant to ask a *different* question, I'd suggest using a new post for that. (If you now change this post to reflect what you really meant, you'll make the existing answered non-sensical.)

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not native english. I suppose I haven't been much clear in my explanations.